# "Bad label content in ILGenerator" when using Reflection Emit

Tags: c#, .net

Some C# code using Reflection Emit is producing the following error message:

> Bad label content in ILGenerator

What can cause this?

Answer (score 7):

I saw this error in some code that called `DefineLabel` but never called `MarkLabel`, yet tried to jump to the label.

Make sure to mark any defined labels that are used.